# typescript - declare structure of subobjects

Tags: typescript

How can I declare structure of objects being children of another objects? I don't know number of children at compile time.

```
let obj = {
    child1: {id: 1, name: "Name id1"},
    child2: {id: 2, name: "Name id2"},
    child3: {id: 3, name: "Name id3"},
    child4: {id: 4, name: "Name id4"},
    child5: {id: 5, name: "Name id5"},
    child6: {id: 6, name: "Name id6"},
}
```

So I want to declare type (or interface) `{id: number, name: string}` and that `obj` can have any property name and value for this property of this new type.

Comment: `obj: { [key: string]: ... }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jonrsharpe

```
interface IdName {id: number, name: string}
let list: { [key: string]: IdName } = {};
```